# Sorting an array of Integers with generics (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm a second year computer science student currently working in Java and we recently started generics. I have an assignment where I've been given a list of sorting algorithms that use generics and am tasked with using them to sort a list of Integers (not primitive ints). As the sort classes use generics that extend Comparable I thought there would be no problems simply handing them the Integer array but the build output keeps coming up with incompatible types.

The relevant code is below;

portion of Main program

```
final int NUMITEMS = 100000;
Integer[] list = new Integer[NUMITEMS];
int dataSize = 0;

//method reads contents of a file into array and returns number of objects
System.out.println((dataSize = readDataFile(list)));

SelectionSort SS = new SelectionSort(list, dataSize);//problem is here
```

And the SelectionSort algorithm which is provided and expected to be used as-is

```
class SelectionSort<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements SortAlgorithm<T>  {

public void  sort ( T [ ] theArray,   int size ) {

  for (int last = size-1; last > 0 ; last--)
  {
     int largest = 0;
     for (int scan = 1; scan <= last; scan++)
        if (theArray[scan].compareTo(theArray[largest])>0)
           largest = scan;

     /** Swap the values */
     T temp = theArray[largest];
     theArray[largest] = theArray[last];
     theArray[last] = temp;
  }
} // method selectionSort
```

The problem I'm having is in declaring SelectionSort, which returns an error that the constructor cannot be applied to the given type. From what I've read in my searches here and elsewhere this kind of problem is usually encountered when using ints, but I don't understand why it isn't working with Integers.
Any insight on the problem would be greatly appreciated as I'm still coming to terms with the concept of generics.
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should fix the problem:

```
SelectionSort<Integer> ss = new SelectionSort<Integer>();
ss.sort(list, dataSize);
```

You were trying to pass arguments into a constructor that didn't exist, when you want to pass them into the `sort` method instead.

Here I'm using the default (no-arg) constructor to instantiate a new `SelectionSort<Integer>`, assigning it to a variable `ss`, then calling `sort` on that instance with the arguments.

Also note that if you just need the instance to call `sort`, you can skip the assignment:

```
new SelectionSort<Integer>().sort(list, dataSize);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `SelectionSort` class is generic. You should specify the type parameter when you declare and instantiate one of them:

```
SelectionSort<Integer> SS = new SelectionSort<Integer>(list, dataSize);
```

In Java 7, you can rely on [type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) to shorten this a bit:

```
SelectionSort<Integer> SS = new SelectionSort<>(list, dataSize);
```

Comment: Ahh, of course! I completely forgot that was necessary! But even with those changes the problem still persists. The build output is:

`error: constructor SelectionSort in class SelectionSort<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  SelectionSort<Integer> SS = new SelectionSort<Integer> (list, dataSize);
                              ^
  required: no arguments
  found: Integer[],int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable<? super T> declared in class SelectionSort
1 error`

Comment: @JorC The SelectionSort class only has a default constructor.  Your the list and data size go into a method call sort.

Comment: That did it. I can't believe I overlooked something so trivial. Fixed it up and it's running fine. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: @JorC - Glad it's fixed. From the looks of it, you could make do with a [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) (not bothering with a generic class).

Comment: @TedHopp I was thinking the same thing, but it looks like the OP may be required to implement the `SortAlgorithm<T>` interface.

Answer (score 3):

```
SelectionSort SS = new SelectionSort(list, dataSize);//problem is here
```

should be

```
SelectionSort<Integer> SS = new SelectionSort<Integer>(list, dataSize);//no problem now
```

your SelectionSort has a parameterized type (sometype which implements comparable). `java.lang.Integer` implements `Comparable`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SelectionSort SS = new SelectionSort(list, dataSize);
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
SelectionSort<Integer> SS = new SelectionSort<Integer>(list, dataSize);
```

You have to declare the parameterized type when you create the object

Comment: I've noticed that generics beginners tend to attribute to generics all compiler error messages related in an way to types. That makes it easy to miss simple things like this one.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the generics issue already covered, I think the code confuses the constructor and the sort method. Change the failing line to:

```
SelectionSort<Integer> SS = new SelectionSort<Integer>();
SS.sort(list, dataSize);
```

The code does not show a SelectionSort constructor, only a sort method which expects the parameters that were being passed to the constructor. The error message is consistent with SelectionSort only having a parameterless constructor supplied by default by the compiler.

Comment: Paul Bellora saw the same problem as I did, and posted his answer just before mine.